# Base addresses and offset values for registers, STM32 documentation

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, datasheet, interrupts

See the document [here](https://www.st.com/resource/en/programming_manual/dm00046982-stm32-cortex-m4-mcus-and-mpus-programming-manual-stmicroelectronics.pdf).

From page 193:

[image]

This table looks like stating that the base address for NVIC block is `0xE000E100`.

---

The table below from page 208 states that `NVIC_ISER0` register is at memory address of `0xE000E100`, which is correct and validated by me in my code.

### [image]

Now, from page 210:

[image]

**This is the part things start to sound wrong to me:** This makes me to think that, "hmm, ISERx registers are the first registers in NVIC block, so, if it is said to have an offset of `0x100`, then it means that base address for NVIC register block is `0xE000E100 - 0x100 = 0xE000E000`. But at this point, it conflicted with the above information which states(or at least I evaluated as so) that the base address for NVIC is `0xE000E100`.

---

And finally, from page 219:

[image]

Which clearly states that both the base address is `0xE000E100` and `NVIC_ISER0` has an offset of `0x100`.

So, where am I wrong at?

Comment: It looks like you are confusing the base address of the *reservation* with the range of addresses within that reservation which are *actually used by registers*, and especially the range used by each of the sub-functions listed in that table.  This seems at best a semantic complaint, is there really any doubt about the actual addresses?   You could always see the driver source files to obtain actual values that (presumably) work.

Comment: @ChrisStratton you are right, as I said in my question, I confirmed the address of NVIC_ISER0. However, the documentation confused me a bit, so I wondered if it is really confusing or I miss something

Answer (score 1):

I believe that offset referred to in Table 4.3.2 is from the bottom of the M4's *System Control Space*. This is defined as part of the M4's `Private Peripheral Bus` (as mentioned in your document). It is a 1 MB address space from `0xE000E000` to `0xE00FFFFF`. So, when it says `Offset 0x100`, that is `0xE000E000 + 0x100` as you've found.

You can read more about the M4's memory mapping in the [technical reference manual](https://static.docs.arm.com/100166/0001/arm_cortexm4_processor_trm_100166_0001_04_en.pdf) on page 3-39, and in the ARMv7-M [architecture reference manual](https://static.docs.arm.com/ddi0403/eb/DDI0403E_B_armv7m_arm.pdf), section B3.

Comment: ok, but how should one know whether the offset is from NVIC base or PPB base? Is not there an ambiguity here?

Comment: @muyustan Yes, I think it's ambiguous. For processor registers, I would use the M4's reference manual rather than the ST manual. It is clear (and you found) that `NVIC_ISERn` starts at `0xE000E100`. If the offset were from the NVIC base, then offset `0x100` would put you at `NVIC_ISPRn`. Hope that helps :)